# How to cancel current activity during the creation of the same one?

Tags: java, android

There is the following code:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MessagesActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 100, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    nb.setContentText("There is a new message for you").setContentTitle("New message").setContentIntent(pi);
    nb.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    nb.setTicker("SomeText").setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    manager.notify(100, nb.getNotification());
```

When user clicks by some notification created with this code the app should open MessagesActivity activity. It works. But if user is in MessagesActivity already this code executes a new copy of MessagesActivity. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to close the existing activity when the user launches it via notification or some other means when it is already running.

Comment: When I click by notification I'd like to close the current activity(is this activity is MessagesActivity) and create a new copy of MessagesActivity. If the current activity is other one I'd like to execute a copy of MessagesActivity without closing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag for your intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MessagesActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

it will not make activity in history stack. so there will be not more than one instance.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP this are other flags that can be used with intent. you can take look at this Intent http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this for your activity in the manifest file?

Add `launchMode="singleTop"` as a property for your activity.

[Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: sorry, but I need to close current MessagesActivity and executes a new copy. Sorry for mistake

Comment: try setting it to "standard", it should be the default one. (The system always creates a new instance of the activity in the target task and routes the intent to it.)